# How to represent a restful representation of a resource and its according collection?

Tags: json, api, rest, data-structures

I'm working on an API and I need to return resource/entity and the like.

Example:

`GET /articles?limit=20&page=5` fetches a ranged collection with 20 items.

`GET /articles/25` fetches an unique identified item.

Basically I would represent those resources respectively like this:

A collection:

```
[
  {
    "id": 12,
    "title": "foo"
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "title": "bar"
  }
]
```

An unique item:

```
{
  "id": 25,
  "title": "baz"
}
```

Which sounds natural.

However, what if I want to include the pagination data?

In a collection, I could do something like:

```
{
  "collection": [
    {
      "id": 12,
      "title": "foo"
    },
    {
      "id": 25,
      "title": "bar"
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
     "item_count": 2,
     "page": 5,
     "limit": 20,
     "total": 102
  }
}
```

The unique item could remains as is, but it looks a bit inconsistent to me, how, a consumer can detect the collection vs the unique item? does he need to check for the "collection" key?

The idea I've is to "type" my result, something like:

For a single item:

```
{
  "type": "item",
  "model": "article",
  "resultKey": "article",
  "article": {
    "id": 25,
    "title": "baz"
  }
}
```

For a collection:

```
{
  "type": "collection",
  "model": "article",
  "resultKey": "articles",
  "articles": [
    {
      "id": 12,
      "title": "foo"
    },
    {
      "id": 25,
      "title": "bar"
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "item_count": 2,
    "page": 5,
    "limit": 20,
    "total": 102
  }
}
```

I could even simplify the key things to conventionally use something like `collection` and `item`.

Some strategy advices to always use a collection and returns a single items, but it sounds unnatural to me, I request an endpoint which returns an entity, I don't except to see a collection, even with only one item.

Is there any normalized json schema to solve this problematic?

Answer (score 0):

I normally do not use a `pagination` item. I actually add links with the appropriate `rel`. [Here is the list of rels](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xml).

There is a `Collection+JSON` [media-type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6573#ref-CollectionJSON).

There is a standard [RFC 6573](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6573).

By following those conventions you are sticking to `HATEOAS` and therefore, decoupling your application from client.

Comment: I know this spec, and I would love to use it, but for several reason, I can't, one of them is, the links provide navigation,  but not the total item count for example, my client needs to be able to display the total item count.